# Databinding with comboxBox in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, linq, wcf-ria-services

I am trying to use a dataContext to populate a comboxbox but always got nothing:

```
EntityQuery<Tests> testQ = myDomainContext.GetTestQuery().Where(t => t == 5);
LoadOperation<Tests> loadOp = myDomainContext.Load(testQ)
comboxBoxTest.ItemSource = loadOp.Entities.Select(t => t.Name).Distinct().ToList();
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't load the entities. Try

```
EntityQuery<Tests> testQ = myDomainContext.GetTestQuery().Where(t => t == 5);
LoadOperation<Tests> loadOp = myDomainContext.Load(testQ);
loadOp.Completed += (o, e) =>
    {
        comboxBoxTest.ItemSource = loadOp.Entities.Select(t => t.Name).Distinct().ToList();
    };
```

Or

```
myDomainContext.Load(testQ, new Action<LoadOperation<Tests>>(result =>
    {
        comboxBoxTest.ItemSource = result.Entities.Select(t => t.Name).Distinct().ToList();
    }), null);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you may know mostly all operations in **`RIA`** are asynch. And you should be aware of this while executing queries.

You have to use callback methods (@Zabavsky's answer has good ones) for such reasons. 
Also I slightly recommend you to use **`MVVM`** pattern instead of code-behind messing. This will make your code and *logic* cleaner.

Comment: Thanks guys. Not a lot of experience working with silverlight anyway. Never used MVVM. This thing is just a quick and dirty fix with almost no time to finish more. Thanks again!